# What are the default values of the char array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, char

If I allocate array of characters like this:

```
char[] buffer = new char[26];
```

what are the default values it is allocated with? I tried to print it and it is just an empty character.

```
System.out.println("this is what is inside=>" + buffer[1]);

this is what is inside=>
```

Is there an ASCII code for it? 
I need to be able to determine if the array is empty or not, and further on, when I fill say first five elements with chars, I need to find out that the sixth element is empty. Thanks.

Comment: default value `\u0000`. test like this `buffer[1] == '\u0000'` that will return `true` if it's not initialized or has default value.

Comment: That's not an ASCII code but a Unicode code point. [This one](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0000/index.htm) to be precise.

Comment: better use collection `List` to check for empty list that auto grow and shrink based on no of elements because checking each and every element in array for empty array will result into `O(n)` complexity which is not good.

Comment: Its an interview question, and they want to see two solutions: with and without using data structures. Working here on the one that does not use linked list

Comment: isn't `\u0000` the same as `\0`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's the same as for any type: the default value for that type. (So the same as you'd get in a field which isn't specifically initialized.)

The default values are specified in [JLS 4.12.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5):

> For type char, the default value is the null character, that is, `'\u0000'`.

Having said that, it sounds like really you want a `List<Character>`, which can keep track of the actual size of the collection. If you need random access to the list (for example, you want to be able to populate element 25 even if you haven't populated element 2) then you could consider:

- A `Character[]` using `null` as the "not set" value instead of `'\u0000'` (which is, after all, still a character...)
- A `Map<Integer, Character>`
- Sticking with `char[]` if you know you'll never, ever, ever want to consider an element with value `'\u0000'` as "set"

(It's hard to know which of these is the most appropriate without knowing more about what you're doing.)

Comment: Its an interview question, and they want to see two solutions: with and without using data structures. Working here on the one that does not use linked list (or hash table).

Comment: Need to determine if the string has all unique characters

Comment: What would be the difference between char and Character data types?

Comment: @user1090944: That sounds like you only need a `boolean[]`. It sounds like you're effectively using a character as a *key*, not a value.

Comment: @user1090944: `char` is a primitive type, `Character` is the wrapper class for it. That's a bigger topic...

Comment: That is a good idea. Use boolean array as hash table where index is a letter and value is either that letter was found previously in the string. Thanks

Comment: @user1090944: It's not a hash table. It's just a simple array. You need to understand that a hash table is rather more complicated.

Comment: I know. It has a hash function. But I was talking about using the concept of the (key, value) pair here

Answer (score 1):

You can also convert it to int and then compare. 
for ex - 
Suppose I declare my array as

```
char[] arr = new char[10];
arr[3]='1';
```

Then, the below code

```
for(char c:arr){
    if((int)c!=0){
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

Will output

```
1
```