# Arrays.sort() removes many items from my array

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting

In my Java program, I have the following code:

```
String[] states = readFile("States.txt");

System.out.println(String.join(" ", states));
System.out.println(states.length);

Arrays.sort(states);

System.out.println(String.join(" ", states));
System.out.println(states.length);
```

Strangely enough, calling `Arrays.sort()` from `java.util.Arrays` causes many items to be removed from the list. When I run the code above, this is the output:

```
FL GA SC NC VA MD NY NJ DE PA CT RI MA VT NH ME AL TN KY WV OH MI MS AR MO KS NE IN IL WI MN LA TX OK IA SD ND NM CO WY ID AZ UT NV MT CA OR WA AL HI
50
AL AL AR AZ CA CO CT DE FL GA HI
50
```

I am very, very confused as to what's going on here. Why are only 11 items printed out? Is `Arrays.sort()` removing items? Why would `Arrays.sort()` do this? Why is the size of the array still `50`? Are the items being blanked out or something?

I assume that my `readFile()` method works fine as the unsorted array prints out fine...

```
public static String[] readFile(String FileName) {
    char[] cbuf = new char[200];
    String[] array;
    FileReader fr;
    try {
        fr = new FileReader(FileName);
        try {
            fr.read(cbuf);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String all = new String(cbuf);
    array = all.split("\n");
    return array;
}
```

The file I am reading from: https://nofile.io/f/8TO3pdnmS3W/States.txt MD5 starts with 8b961b5

Comment: Looks like your readFile is also including the new line character for the last item - in this case HI. - try all.split(System.lineSeparator())

Comment: The text file does not contain a new line at the end of the file. If I add one, sorting the array causes nothing at all to be printed out, and it says size is `51`.

Comment: Try splitting with whitespace. all.split("\\s").

Comment: Smth is terribly wrong, if you're getting your array and it outputs all states, but after Arrays.sort() it doesnt - cant be :) why dont you debug your code before and after sort() fn?

Comment: Also, why don't you try by hardcoding the `states` array?

Comment: @KDM Same results as with `\n` @user7 I have to read from this exact text file.

Comment: Reason for size being the same is, Array does not remove the element from it, it just reference that element to null and hence there wont be any change in the size

Comment: The program works if I add `ZZ` to the end of the list, which causes it to print everything. It seems like it stops sorting when it reaches the last item in the original list. But I can't add `ZZ` to the end of the list in the final version of my program.

Comment: Use Arrays.toString(states) to print arrays in Java. :D

Comment: With `String[] states = "FL GA SC NC VA MD ...".split(" ");` there is no problem. Check if `split("\n");` apply to all the data in the file (there aren't any `\r\n` delimiters for example).

Comment: @DataDino when I use `Arrays.toString(states);` I get `[AL, AL, AR, AZ, CA, CO, CT, DE, FL, GA, HI` with no ending bracket?

Comment: How do I check for delimiters in the file? All I did was copy text and paste it into a text file with Mousepad (on Linux) and saved it as `States.txt`.

Comment: @AaronFranke, then your log is truncating the output! Arrays.toString() will work. Go check for truncation.

Comment: i have replicated the sort code by declaring the array directly [initialized while declaring] and i am not missing any words in the output array after it is sorted. Are you sure that the array is of 50 size while it is read from the file?

Comment: I susepect a ^Z in the data file.

Comment: @AaronFranke debug the program and check the values in `states`. If there was `\r` the values will look like `"FL\r"`.

Comment: I don't know how to debug a program and check values. But `trim()`ming the input fixes the problem.

Comment: Learning to use the debugger is essential, try to put this high on your todo list. It will save you hours of pain and confusion. The reason trim() works is because your string has a bunch of null character values at the end as a result of your buffer being longer than your input and trim() removes them. It would be better to use a smaller buffer, or at least check the return value of fr.read() to see how many characters you read, and use that knowledge when you convert it to a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The newline character at the end of the file, specifically after the last entry in the file "`HI`", seems to be causing the problem. It can be solved in the `readFile` function by using:

`array = all.trim().split("\n");`

Comment: This works perfectly! But, there were no newline characters at the end of the file. The file appears to simply end after `HI` , but I suppose there were some kind of ghost characters hiding at the end of the file. Maybe it's my text editor's fault. I can upload the file if y'all want to investigate further.

Comment: Please do upload the file. It may help some of us to pin-point the problem. Also I emulated your input by inserting a `newline` (`newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");` ) at the end of the space-separated  input you provided. Observed similar behaviour. Although I should mention that although the output breaks after `HI`, the rest of the output printed in a new line.

Comment: I uploaded the file, there's a link at the bottom of my question. I also posted the first part of the MD5 sum to check if you have the exact same file. Furthermore, my IDE that I am using to show output is Eclipse 4.6.3.

Comment: It may have been an issue with the fact that my buffer was larger than the input, and that is the reason why it needs trimming. See @Matt 's answer

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed the 'artifact' behavior via the Online Java Compiler :

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // instead of using readFile() the array is defined here.
        // note the \n on the last element
        String[] states = {"FL", "GA", "SC", "NC", "VA", "MD", "NY", "NJ", "DE", "PA", "CT", "RI", "MA", "VT", "NH", "ME", "AL", "TN", "KY", "WV", "OH", "MI", "MS", "AR", "MO", "KS", "NE", "IN", "IL", "WI", "MN", "LA", "TX", "OK", "IA", "SD", "ND", "NM", "CO", "WY", "ID", "AZ", "UT", "NV", "MT", "CA", "OR",
           "WA", "AL", "HI\n"};

        System.out.println(String.join(" ", states));
        System.out.println(states.length);

        Arrays.sort(states);

        System.out.println(String.join(" ", states));
        System.out.println(states.length);
    }
}
```

And the Output:

```
FL GA SC NC VA MD NY NJ DE PA CT RI MA VT NH ME AL TN KY WV OH MI MS AR MO KS NE IN IL WI MN LA TX OK IA SD ND NM CO WY ID AZ UT NV MT CA OR WA AL HI

50
AL AL AR AZ CA CO CT DE FL GA HI
 IA ID IL IN KS KY LA MA MD ME MI MN MO MS MT NC ND NE NH NJ NM NV NY OH OK OR PA RI SC SD TN TX UT VA VT WA WI WV WY
50
```

Apparently the log used by @Arjun Kay had truncated the elements printed after the sorted element with the break-line character.

Comment: Actually, the issue was that after `HI` there were many null characters in the `char[]` buffer, which caused the text to stop printing.

Answer (score 1):

Your `readFile` method is sloppy. You declare a buffer array `char[] cbuf = new char[200];` with 200 elements.

It sounds like your file is formatted with a state on each line:

```
FL
GA
SC
NC
```

You read the entire file into your buffer, but you don't fill the buffer so the trailing 50 elements are still initialised to the default null character value `\u0000` (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35620464/what-are-the-default-values-of-the-char-array-in-java))

```
cbuf = [F][L][\n][G][A][\n][S][C][\n][N][C][\n] ... [\u0000][\u0000]
```

Then you convert `cbuff` to a string:

```
all = "FL\nGA\nSC\nNC\n ... \u0000\u0000\u0000"
```

Then you split the string to convert it to an array:

```
array = [FL][GA][SC][NC]...[\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000]
```

So you can see you have a bunch of useless characters in your final array, because your buffer was bigger than the file that you read.

I can't replicate your missing states on my machine, but you could clean up your file reader and I think it will work for you. Use a `BufferedReader`, then you can read your file a line at a time and it will save you all the manual splitting. I would also recommend using a `List<String>` instead of a `String[]` array, so you don't have to handle the size of the array.

Consider this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String[] states = readFile("States.txt");

    System.out.println(String.join(" ", states));
    System.out.println(states.length);

    Arrays.sort(states);

    System.out.println(String.join(" ", states));
    System.out.println(states.length);

    // now do the same thing but using a list
    List<String> statesList = readFileToList("States.txt");

    System.out.println(String.join(" ", statesList));
    System.out.println(statesList.size());

    Collections.sort(statesList);

    System.out.println(String.join(" ", statesList));
    System.out.println(statesList.size());
}

// read the file to an array
public static String[] readFile(String FileName) throws IOException {
    String[] states = new String[50];
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FileName));

    String state;
    int index = 0; // keep track of the array index
    // when readLine() returns null there are no more lines to read
    while((state = br.readLine()) != null && index < 50) {
        states[index] = state;
        index++;
    }

    return states;
}

// read the file to a list
public static List<String> readFileToList(String FileName) throws IOException {
    List<String> states = new ArrayList<>(); // no array size to worry about
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FileName));

    String state;
    while((state = br.readLine()) != null) {
        states.add(state); // no indexes to worry about
    }

    return states;
}
```

Comment: Normally I'd agree about `List`s, but for this specific program I was required to use a String array. And if you would like to test with the original text file I've added it to my question.

Comment: If you have to use an array that's fair. I tested with the file you uploaded and my code works fine. I'm pretty sure your problem was related to your buffer being bigger than your input.

Comment: Just tested it. With a buffer of `150`, the bug occurs, but with `149`, the bug no longer occurs. I had no idea having a larger buffer than necessary could cause issues. Still, `.trim()` is an easier solution in my case.

Comment: @AaronFranke Even if you need an array, the convenience of using [`Files#readAllLines`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-) and doing a `toArray` on the result is a strong argument here (on top of the argument that the cases where you **really** need to read raw `char[]` arrays are rare...)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `BufferedReader` for reading a line from the `FileReader` like this

```
 public static String[] readFile(String FileName) {
        ArrayList<String> stringArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader;

        try {
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FileName));
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringArrayList.add(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stringArrayList.toArray(new String[0]);
    }
```

Comment: Covered with [`Files#readAllLines`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-), basically...